# How to know when a request started?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Browsers such as Chrome can only execute [6ish parallel requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/574190).

If we attempt to simultaneously initiate more than 6 requests at once,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; 1++) {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open('GET', URL);
  oReq.send();
}
```

then the browser will queue them up and execute them in batches of 6.

[image: requests in browser]

**Is it possible to tell when a request had moved from the "waiting" state to actually being executed?**

The `onloadstart` event seems to fire when the request is added to the queue rather than when it actually starts loading.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked about the [readyState property of HttppRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp) ? Maybe it will cover your question..

XMLHttpRequest Object Properties

readyState:

Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest. Changes from 0 to 4:

0: request not initialized

1: server connection established

2: request received

3: processing request

4: request finished and response is ready

So using this info you could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; 1++) {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open('GET', URL);
  oReq.send();

  oReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (oReq.readyState == 4 && oReq.status == 200) {   
      //do something like an alert
      //you can get rid of the oReq.status if you want and 
      //just track the readyState (0-4)
    };
  };
}
```